# Tem como chamar um método quando o aplicativo é fechado?

Tags: java, android

Oque acontece quando o usuário fecha o aplicativo sem chamar um método pré definido no app, oque eu quero dizer é quando ele remove o app da lista de aplicativos  ativos.Oque acontece neste momento?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Pelo o que entendi você quer que o método "Apagar tudo" seja chamado sempre antes da aplicação terminar. Já que isso é dificil por várias questões, por que você não chama esse metodo antes da aplicação começar? Quero dizer, se a tabela estiver preenchida antes da aplicação começar a inserir dados então deverão ser apagados porque é 'lixo' da utilização anterior.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Uma opção é explorar o próprio [ciclo de vida](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle) da sua atividade principal. Por exemplo, quando é usado o recurso do dispositivo "Apagar tudo", neste caso, a atividade principal de sua aplicação chamará o método [`onDestroy()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onDestroy()) que faz parte do ciclo de vida de uma *activity*. Sendo assim, você pode inserir a ação para "remover uma child" dentro do `onDestroy()`. Insira o método na sua `MainActivity` e faça um teste usando um `Toast`. Veja um exemplo:

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Toast.makeText(this,"Aplicação destruída com o onDestroy()",
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

<sup>**Nota:** Para o seu propósito, existem outras formas de fazer isso, por exemplo usando [*Services*](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html?hl=pt-br).</sup>

Comment: Obrigado Ack Lay!

Comment: apesar de ser oque eu queria não vai dar muito certo tem a probabilidade ainda do celular desligar repentinamente.

Comment: A resposta está de acordo e responde sua pergunta de maneira eficiente, porém há outras formas talvez mais eficaz de fazer isso, por exemplo usando Service.

Comment: Assim a resposta foi muito útil, mais depois que pensei nesse problema, valeu pela nova dica!

Comment: A sua pergunta é meio que uma pergunta XY, porque o método mais adequado de verificar a quantidade de usuários ativos é usando o onDisconnect(). Tem um artigo específico sobre isso aqui: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2013/06/how-to-build-presence-system.html

Comment: .info/connected resolveu meu problema